# How to save multipage tiff with multiple pixel formats to a single pixel format?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, pixelformat

I need to detect if a multipage tiff's page pixel formats and change them if they are not `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`. Normally that would be simple enough for me to do. For the same reason I need to do the conversions, I seem to be having issues with coming up with an ideal solution.

if the active frame of the image is `PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed` and then I try to change to a frame with that has `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`, `WorkingImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);` throws an exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

I suppose I could catch the exception and reopen the image/image stream and continue checking but I'm hoping that this isn't my only option.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Working with multipage TIF using System.Drawing can be tricky to say the least. That's probably why there are dedicated imaging libraries that contain much more elaborate TIFF support.
The following code may not be the ideal solution to your specific problem, but it worked when tested with a TIFF file that had 1-bit, 8-bit and 24-bit pages, converting them all to 24-bit. The code creates new 24-bit pages and appends them all to a new file, leaving the original unchanged.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(outputTif))
   System.IO.File.Delete(outputTif);
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(inputTif);
Bitmap multiPageImage = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
multiPageImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, 0);
Bitmap firstPage = new Bitmap(multiPageImage.Width, multiPageImage.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(firstPage);
g.DrawImageUnscaled(multiPageImage, 0, 0);
g.Dispose();
ImageCodecInfo TiffCodec = null;
foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
   if (codec.MimeType == "image/tiff")
   {
      TiffCodec = codec;
      break;
   }
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(2);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
parameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, (long)24);
//save the first page in a new file
firstPage.Save(outputTif, TiffCodec, parameters);
parameters = new EncoderParameters(2);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
parameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, (long)24);
var pageCount = multiPageImage.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);
//now append pages from second to last
for (int i = 1; i < pageCount; ++i)
{
   multiPageImage = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
   multiPageImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
   Bitmap nextPage = new Bitmap(multiPageImage.Width, multiPageImage.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
   g = Graphics.FromImage(nextPage);
   g.DrawImageUnscaled(multiPageImage, 0, 0);
   g.Dispose();
   firstPage.SaveAdd(nextPage, parameters);
   nextPage.Dispose();
}
parameters = new EncoderParameters(2);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
parameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.LastFrame);
firstPage.SaveAdd(parameters);
firstPage.Dispose();
```